# Oracle SQL Query to get missing date from two joined tables

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to write a Oracle SQL query and I'm unable to get the right result.

For the tables below, I would like to first get all records from DEVICE where DEVICE.MODEL='UNITA' and for those results, give me the DEVICE.CUSTOMER_ID's who don't have a record where PROFILE.TYPE='TEST' joining both tables on CUSTOMER_ID.  Any ideas on how to formulate this query?

```
TABLE DEVICE:
ID - sequence generated primary key (NUMBER (10))
DEVICE_NUMBER - unique (varchar)
CUSTOMER_ID (varchar)
MODEL (varchar)

TABLE PROFILE:
ID - sequence generated primary key (NUMBER (10))
CUSTOMER_ID (varchar)
TYPE (varchar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Device_Number, d.Customer_ID, d.Model
FROM Device d
LEFT JOIN Profile p ON d.Customer_ID = p.Customer_ID
WHERE d.Model = 'UNITA'
  AND (p.ID IS NULL OR p.Type = 'TEST')
```

It works because of the `LEFT JOIN`, which will make `Profile.ID` NULL if there's not a matching `Profile` row for the `Customer_ID`. If there is a matching row, the test for `Profile.Type = 'TEST'` will determine what's included.

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/028d8/5). The Fiddle includes the `Profile.ID` and `Profile.Type` values in the results because I think they help explain things more clearly.

---

**Addendum**: Some confusion on my part over the requirements; this query may be closer to what's needed:

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Device_Number, d.Customer_ID, d.Model, p.id AS pid, p.type
FROM Device d
LEFT JOIN Profile p ON d.Customer_ID = p.Customer_ID AND p.Type = 'TEST'
WHERE d.Model = 'UNITA'
  AND p.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I wasn't able to get the data I want and I think it is due to some vagueness in my question. The query you provided is not showing me any null PID and null TYPE for my dataset.  The join of the customer id will always yield atleast one or more records from the profile table.  What I need is to find the customers that are missing a profile.type of 'TEST'

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that. I've added another query as an addendum to my answer. If it's not exactly what you need I think it's at least closer. Can you give it a try? There's a new Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d82901/1).